# Ubuntu won't boot and get this on a black screen /dev/sda5: clean

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

So I have a dual boot of Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 7. I wanted to expand my Ubuntu partition so freed some space from my E: drive in windows and moved it towards the Ubuntu so that using a live USB I could use GParted to extend it. But when I tried to open my Ubuntu before using a live usb to extend I get stuck 9on a black screen with the following message

> /dev/sda5: clean, 103596/1978592 files, 7631618/7900672 blocks

I have tried using the suggested solutions like boot-repair, nomodset and also pressing cntrl + Alt + F2 or F3 in order to login into terminal but nothing works.

Can someone please provide me a solution to make it work please, I don't want to reinstall the entire Ubuntu, that will be my last option.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred Here is the pastebin link of the recent Boot-repair as mentioned by you I have used the ppa version from the start. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VYnq5jPHHR/

Comment: Looks normal. BIOS installs of both Windows & Ubuntu. What video card/chip? Have you tried recovery mode? some suggestions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @oldfred Do I tried booting with replacing **quick splash** with **nomodeset** in the grub edit menu and then I get this **[74.833333] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: HSW/BDW HD-Audio HDMI/DP requires binding with gfx driver**. I guess this is an issue with the driver, can help me with it please I'm a beginner at Ubuntu and I have a deadline tomorrow, it's really important to recover it asap. Thanks in advance

Comment: Often video driver controls audio also. What video card/chip? Did it boot and audio not work? What brand/model system, some need other boot parameters in addition to nomodeset.

Comment: @oldfred Also I don't have nvidea graphics, I have Intel HD and AMD Radeon HD 8670M, Sometimes I have weird issues with my mic on Ubuntu but it works. Also right noe on my windows the audio is working fine but in the device manager it shows AMD Radeon as **Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)**. I have a Dell Inspiron 3537 (i5).

Comment: Cannot fix hardware issues with software. The correct AMD video driver is supposed to be installed automatically during install.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved, faced same issue.

Before doing this, turn on your internet, reboot PC and it will connect your PC to internet (if previously connected) or find, how connect internet via command after step 1, given below.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>: Enter your Username & Password
2. Check gdm version: `sudo service --status-all |grep gdm`
3. Install your gdm (in my case it was gdm3): `sudo apt install gdm3`

All done...